# Flexdashboard and Datatable - not rendering enough rows

Tags: dt, flexdashboard

This Rmd code is rendering outputs that display less than the expected number of rows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
params:
  color_target: H
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Color
==============================
  
Color
------------------------------

  
```{r}
 diamonds %>% 
  filter(str_detect(color,  params$color_target)) %>%
  DT::datatable() 
```
````

As seen in the screenshot,  it generates tables that have only 3 or 4 rows displayed, rather than the default (for example) 10 rows.

Expected behaviour: Many pages of tables with 10 rows,all visible.

Comment: Screenshot to follow shortly.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Lhr.png Note how only 3 or 4 rows are displayed.  I was expecting 10.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (dah!) was just the vertical space allocated to the table.  All the rows were there and if I had looked more closely I would have seen the vertical slider.